# get text from non window class

Tags: opera

I am trying to get url from opera browser. In Spy++, you can have a target cursor where it detects window control and give you class name. When I hover it over Opera's address bar, it can't detect the url control so i assume it is drawn internally. Is there a way to get text from the class? I am using MFC and for IE8, I am sending wm_Gettext message to get text.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One workaround would be to show the URL in Opera's title bar. Copypaste `opera:config#show address` into the address bar, check the box and save. If that's what you're looking for.